# Who will contribute to and edit the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

Blog discussion time! In [discussions on the Meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-it-time-for-a-home-improvement-blog) we've established that we probably do want a blog to [tell stories and share pictures and media that don't fit into the format of questions-and-answers](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/if-its-time-for-a-blog-what-will-the-scope-and-organization-of-the-blog-look-li). The next step that we have to decide on is **who is willing to contribute** to the blog, and **who will edit the contributions**.

As far as content -- A lot of people seem to have stories to tell if the Thursday Project chats are any indication. We've identified a few that we definitely want -- such as ongoing projects like @Jay Bazuzi's yurt, the variety of projects (from full guts to quick flips) that I'm working on with friends, and experienced contractors like [Steve Jackson](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/517/steve-jackson) and their wealth of jobsite stories and experience. However, we need to establish a consistent way for users to get access to the blog to contribute.

Another issue with the blog is that we have to have an active editorial staff to make sure that content gets posted on a timely basis and meets standards. We need people who are willing to log in and read contributions, edit them for factual content and grammar without changing the core content, and post them. I would like to have several people involved with this process.

So the second thing that we need to establish here is how the blog will be edited, who will have editor/administrator access, and how long that access will last (if not "as long as the user is active") and how successors are appointed. Those people will then be responsible for setting editorial standards, recruiting posters, and establishing a schedule of some sort.

(Note: I am *specifically* asking for people who want to contribute and to edit the blog to step forward here as an answer. I'm willing to lead to an extent, but I do have a tendency to run off for a month at a time to gut part of a house.)

Comment: Pinging @shirlock. We would love to hear some stories from the job site.

Comment: Pinging @Jay Bazuzi. The yurt project would make a good series of blog posts I'm sure.

Comment: I had an answer to another meta question that had some example questions I thought might transition to blog posts.  We might have to do lots more pinging to get all those folks over to meta.  http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/325/is-it-time-for-a-home-improvement-blog/373#373

Answer (score 6):

Sorry Karl, not a contractor (at least not the useful GC kind).  I think you're thinking of [Michael](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1354/michael).

I can help with editing and nagging and posts when I get to some projects.  I'd love to see this get off the ground (mostly because I want to read it).

Comment: Dangit, I thought you were! I probably am thinking of Michael, but I thought it was you that was sharing "jobsite stories" in chat several weeks back. I suppose I could go and look...

Answer (score 5):

I can help with the editorial tasks and may be able to contribute articles from time to time (though I'm not good at taking photos during a job... I get too involved in doing).

Answer (score 4):

I'll be happy to contribute stories and reviews.

I'm a techie, not an English major, so if spell check doesn't catch it, my editorial skills quickly decline.

Answer (score 3):

Count me in.

I'll help anywhere I'm needed.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely will have stories to tell as the years go by.  I own and/or operate 3 rental properties (6 units) plus we have major projects planned in our own house and long term plan to acquire more real estate and do a lot of the work ourselves.

I take lots of pictures too. :)