# Chat session to discuss ways of promoting the site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

It's been suggested that a chat session to discuss ways of promoting the site would be a good idea. We already have [a question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-we-promote-our-site) with some ideas, but the thought is now is the time to act on some of these.

I agree with this, and (assuming others do too) the next step is to find a time that's suitable for the most number of people interested in participating.

I'm in the UK so something around 22:00 UTC on a weekday would suit me the best, though I could probably arrange to be around earlier on a weekend, but I'm probably in a minority here.

So when can we hold this?

Comment: It seems to me that weekend traffic is **much** lower than during the week.  Do you have access to traffic statistics in the moderator-only tools that might give you an idea of when most people are on here?

Comment: @Niall - yes there are stats. I'll check. There's a dip on Saturdays, but Sundays seem to be as busy as the rest of the week.

Comment: Speaking of During-the-week stats, when does traffic usually hit a high during the week? we can schedule a chat during peak hours that way. And, hopefully, include the other DIY mods whom I haven't met.

Comment: @aarthi - traffic is fairly flat with Saturday being the only day with a significant dip. Though it's difficult to tell for sure.

Comment: Do we know if there's a certain time of day that our traffic peaks? If not, then let's just schedule this for, oh, between 20:00-22:00 UTC? Those are better times for me, though if it needs to be later then I'm game. I'd *really* like for our other mods and major users to be present there.

Comment: Maybe there's a dip on Saturdays since that's when everyone's out doing what they asked about during the week.

Answer (score 1):

The chat happened.

You can see what we discussed by reading [the transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/conversation/diy-site-promotion-chat).

Please add anything else you can think of as answers to this question or [this older question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-we-promote-our-site).

Answer (score 0):

Given that Chris is in the U.K. and I'm on the East Coast of the U.S., and that a number of our users share my time zone, I'm thinking some time in the afternoon here would be best. Say, perhaps, 15:00 (3pm) on Wednesday? I'm not married to that time, but I have a scheduled chat with Parenting tomorrow.

[edit] I'm pretty much available whenever -- rather, I will make myself available whenever. I'm not awesome in the mornings, as a warning, but after lunch and into the evenings is fine. I'd rather not meet after 22:00 (10pm) EST, though.

Answer (score 0):

We need to get at least one question a week in the "hot questions" list.  All of those questions get a few thousand views each, which would bring in maybe 10 new users a week.

I visit SE pretty much daily, and I've only seen one question from Home Improvement in hot questions (something about guessing the height of a tree.)  I don't know who's in charge of that, but if it's something that we have a little control over, we should take advantage of it.  Avoid being spammy, of course, but there's more than enough good questions to put one a week in there.