# Chat session to discuss site promotion - Wednesday 17th August, 21:00 UTC

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, chat

Right - time is moving on so we need to get this moving. Based on discussions arising from [this question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359/chat-session-to-discuss-ways-of-promoting-the-site) I think the best time for this would be **this Wednesday** at 21:00 UTC.

That's:

- 22:00 BST
- 17:00 EDT (Eastern Daylight)
- 14:00 PDT (Pacific Daylight)

I think it would be easiest to hold it in the normal [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111) room and we'll post a transcript after we've done. I don't think we'd want it to be longer than an hour.

There's a [chat meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/111/home-improvement?tab=schedule) scheduled if you want a reminder.

*Feel free to correct my time zone conversions*

Comment: If anyone's having trouble converting (Lord knows I was) then use this site: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meeting.html

Answer (score 1):

The chat happened.

You can see what we discussed by reading [the transcript](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111/conversation/diy-site-promotion-chat).

Please add anything else you can think of as answers to this question or [this older question](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/how-do-we-promote-our-site).

Copied from [here](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359/chat-session-to-discuss-ways-of-promoting-the-site/365#365). :D